# Rails ActiveRecord Query - How to create a complex, multi-relation conditional query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was trying to figure out how to query my database using a custom method within my model.  As far as I can tell, this is not possible, so I'm looking for alternative ideas.

The challenge is that I need to find all records of a model where at least one relational condition is true.  For example, lets say that I have a `Notebook` record and I need to find all instances of `Notebook` that had at least one of their related objects modified.  Let's say a `Notebook` has a `front_cover`, `back_cover`, `interior_pages`, and `interior_folders`.  Within my `Notebook` model class I have this method:

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :front_cover
  has_one :back_cover
  has_many :interior_pages
  has_many :interior_folders
  ...
  def modified?
    if !front_cover.modified? or !back_cover.modified? or !interior_pages.empty? or !interior_folders.empty?
      return true
    end
    false
  end
  ...
end
```

The modified methods within `front_cover` and `back_cover` may have their own relationships that they will check as well:

```
class FrontCover < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cover_graphic
  has_many :ring_holes
  belongs_to :notebook
  ...
  def modified?
    modified = false
    if (!cover_graphic.nil? and !cover_graphic.url.nil?) or !ring_holes.empty?
      modified = true
    end        
    modified
  end
end
```

I'm really not sure how I can construct such a conditional check as a query. Any ideas?

Comment: More code is needed; more specifically: how do you tell that a `FrontCover` has been modified? Is there a column in the database that keeps track? Is it a special type of query? Modified since when?

Comment: Added another example.

Comment: [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) contains useful methods to do that on db-level also, if you add column "modified" to FrontCover as Momer suggested. You can join FrontCovers to Notebook and count how many modified FrontCovers every Notebooks have. After that take only Notebooks with at least one modified Notebook. I suggest to use rails console to construct correct ActiveRecord/DB-query.

Comment: Well, the "modified?" value is a method on the FrontCover class, but let's assume I do add a 'modified' column to FrontCover and BackCover.  I'm guessing that I could add a before_save filter to both of those classes to update the modified attribute by calling the "modified?" method.  Then I suppose I could I could do a count check that at least one of those associations has a 'modified' field set to true.  Is that what you guys are suggesting?